# Emacs metaprogramming, dynamically define methods

Tags: emacs, macros, elisp, metaprogramming

I am trying to define some helper functions to quickly jump to different projects from within emacs. I started by defining a macro as follows

```
(defmacro project-alias (name path)
  `(defun ,name ()
     (interactive)
     (cd ,path)))
```

And this works great I can `(project-alias foo "~/bar")` no problem. The problem comes when I try and apply this macro over a list of tuples.

```
(setq projects '((foo . "~/foo")
                 (bar . "~/bar")))

(dolist (p projects)
  (project-alias (car p) (cdr p)))
```

The above code errors with

```
Debugger entered--Lisp error: (wrong-type-argument symbolp (car p))
  defalias((car p) (lambda nil (interactive) (cd (cdr p))))
```

I have tried passing the first argument in as a string and calling `intern` to get the symbol representation out with no joy, and I've also tried defining my macro to accept the string form and that doesn't work either

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do either

```
(defun project-alias-f (name path)
  (eval `(defun ,name ()
       (interactive)
       (cd ,path))))



(dolist (p projects)
  (project-alias-f (car p) (cdr p)))
```

or

```
(dolist (p projects)
  (eval `(project-alias ,(car p) ,(cdr p))))
```

Answer (score 4):

If your use of the macro involves ***evaluating*** sexps to produce the name and path, then it needs to evaluate the sexps:

```
(defmacro project-alias (name path)
  `(defun ,(eval name) () (interactive) (cd ,(eval path))))
```

Alternatively, use a function:

```
(defun project-alias (name path)
  (eval `(defun ,name () (interactive) (cd ,path))))
```

Answer (score 1):

Macro arguments are passed *un-evaluated*. (Macros could not otherwise do what they can do.)

So your arguments are literally the forms `(car p)` and `(cdr p)` (as opposed to, for instance, `foo` and `"~/foo"`).

Answer (score 1):

Here's another take on it, with no macros nor eval:

```
;; -*- lexical-binding:t -*-

(defun project-alias-f (name filename)
  (defalias name (lambda () (interactive) (cd filename)))

(dolist (p projects)
  (project-alias-f (car p) (cdr p)))
```

Comment: It seems the `filename` is not evaluated.

Comment: What makes it "seem" so?  If you get a `void-variable: filename` kind of error, it's probably because there was a problem with the `;; -*- lexical-binding:t -*-` (it needs to be on the first line of the file and if you used `C-x C-e` or `M-C-x` it only works if the line was already there when you opened the file).

Comment: Oh, yes. But it seems that can not work on emacs23 but emacs24.

Comment: Oh, indeed, lexical-binding is a feature introduced in Emacs-24.1

Answer (score 0):

This is not an answer to your macro problem, but an alternative solution to your desire to jump between projects.

In my init.el file, I have (amongst other things)

```
(set-register ?A '(file . "~/.aliases"))
(set-register ?E '(file . "~/.emacs.d/init.el"))
(set-register ?H '(file . "~/.hgrc"))
(set-register ?T '(file . "~/.TODO.org"))
```

Then I can use `jump-to-register` (`C-x r j`) to jump to one of these files when I wish to edit the file (or do something with one of the unlisted projects). Because a file/folder is stored in the register (rather than a window config say), emacs will open the file or folder it finds in the register.

Comment: thanks. That looks like a useful thing to know, but not really what I'm after - my use case is that I use Projectile mode heavily to open files in a project, and the easiest way to set the context correctly is to tell emacs to cd into the project before opening Projectile.